# Set the value for the email field in SugarPro

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, sugarcrm

I'm working on SugarPro, where I need to set the value for email field in js file. I can able to set the value for the remaining field except the email field, through `self.model.set('email','value');`.

And I tried by setting the value through jquery, it is working but while saving the value is not taking. It is empty.
How can I set the value for the email field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the default email fields and this is Sugar 7

The email field accepts an array of objects that represent the entire payload of the email field (The email field is not a standard text field)

```
var emails = [
    {
        email_address: "test@test.com",
        primary_address: true,
    },
    {
        email_address: "test2@test.com",
        primary_address: false,
    },
]


model.set('email', emails);
```